# How to properly add Twitter Bootstrap to meteor

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

How can I properly install Twitter Bootstrap into my meteor project?

I know I can do `meteor add bootstrap` but I can't customize the variables (ie colors and the sorts). I've also looked at [nemo64:bootstrap](https://github.com/Nemo64/meteor-bootstrap) but same issue, I can only include and exclude modules of Twitter Bootstrap but not the variables.

How can I properly include Twitter Bootstrap and have access to the `variables.less` ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to control the order in which Meteor loads .less files you need to add .import.less to the file extension. If you import the bootstrap less files into your project and rename them, you will have finite control of all the mixins and variables. Here is a great post that summarizes this. http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-twitter-bootstrap---the-right-way